# Is it possible to sign anywhere on pdf in DocuSign embedded signing?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign in our application. We want to give signers an ability to sign anywhere on the pdf instead of a particular signature coordinates. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply do not include any tabs for the signer when you create the envelope.

Then, when the embedded signing ceremony is shown, the signer will see a set of tabs on the left column that they can place in the document, and then sign.

However, our studies show that this user interface (the signer choosing where to sign the document) results in fewer completed signing sessions since it is more work for the signer.

We recommend that you place the tab(s) for the signer. If you don't want to use absolute positioning, you can use auto-placement via anchor text.